# Is this DNS setup correct

Tags: domain-name-system

Won't go into full details of problems here but we are seeing some unreliability in pinging domain.local so I wondered if the DNS records are correct:

- SOA, Primary server: "server.domain.local." (note final dot)
- NS, "server.domain.local." (note final dot again), 192.168.10.5
- A, Host: (same as parent folder), FQDN: Domain.local, IP:
  192.168.10.5
- A, Host: server, FQDN: server.Domain.local, IP: 192.168.10.5

My main concern is whether it is correct to have two records for server.domain.local(.), one NS record and one A record?

Comment: No, that is incorrect. You should not invent new tld's, and especially .local is problematic as it's used by bonjour/mdns already.

Comment: Very confused by your comment Dennis, this is an internal domain, every Windows server that I have ever worked on is on a DomainX.local subnet.  Microsoft uses .local as the default why is this now incorrect?

Comment: Please read: http://www.mdmarra.com/2012/11/why-you-shouldnt-use-local-in-your.html

Comment: Interesting article.  However doesn't make any suggestions to use (instead of .local) when there is no relevant company domain for the active directory.

Comment: Either way that kind of gets away from the point, basic question (disregarding the .local question), is if the above DNS entries look correct or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is correct. The name server record (NS) designates which server is the name server for the zone, but it needs to resolve/point to to an A record, which in turn resolves to an ip address. That is what the A record for the NS record is for.

DNS records such as NS and MX records need a corresponding A record. Think of the NS, MX, SRV, etc. records as "pointers". So if I ask "Who is the name server for blahblah.com?" I'll get an answer of "ns.blahblah.com is the name server for blahblah.com". Then I need to ask "What is the ip address of ns.blahblah.com?" and the answer comes from the A record (the host record).

Comment: Thanks joeqwerty, that answers the question regarding the NS record.

Comment: Glad to help...